How can I read Microsoft 365 Acronyms without explicit Graph permissions?
I'm trying to read the list of Acronyms in Microsoft 365 Search, using this endpoint: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/search-searchentity-list-acronyms?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
All works fine to read with delegated permissions if the user is a Search Admin or a Search Editor role, but I can't even READ the acronyms unless the user is at least one of those roles. A user without either of those roles can find an acronym fine in the M365 Search results, so ultimately they do (and should) have at least a read capability somewhere, but is there no way to just READ them from Graph directly, which I need to do in order to show the full list of Acronyms (or Q&A, or Bookmarks, etc.)?
I know I could put an API in the middle, with Application permissions, but that's a lot of extra work (including coordination with several other teams interally), for something that should probably 'just work'.
